# teradata role name max length 30 is too short for Ad group name

Tags: teradata, kerberos

I am working on a Teradata (TD) and Active Directory (AD) sync script for a Teradata LDAP integration project.  Soon we realize that many long AD group names was truncated in TD role names because of TD's max length of 30 characters for a role name.

I am wondering if there is a work around for this issue?

I can maintain a mapping text file of AD role name to AD ground name or a table as a look up method.

Any other suggestions?

Great appreciated!

Comment: TD14.10 supports names up to 128 characters, before you're probably out of luck...

Comment: Oh! Great, I am using TD15.  So I must find a way to turn on the 128 character option.  We have a paid subscription support to TD.  I will raise an incident to TD tomorrow.

Comment: It's controlled by two dbscontrol settings: General fields 75: NameValidationRule and 76: EnableEON

Comment: I'm reluctant to move to 128 character object names. That's nearly the length of a tweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easist way to fix this issue is to use the latest Views to look for role names.  The old names such as dbc.RoleMember has the limitation of 30 characters.

```
select *
  from dbc.roleMembersV
 where RoleName like '%TERA%TEST%'
 order by roleName asc
;
```